# Prevent jBoss/Seam to handle the exception for me

Tags: java, exception, jboss, seam

I have the problem, that I try to catch a `jboss.seam.security.NotLoggedInException` if the user is not logged in and wants to reach a resource where that has to be the case.

That is working kinda well with this piece of xml in the `pages.xml`

```
<exception class="org.jboss.seam.security.NotLoggedInException">
        <redirect view-id="/home.xhtml">
                <message severity="warn">
                        #{messages['system.error.exception.notLoggedIn']}
                </message>
        </redirect>
</exception>
```

Now i have the problem, that it shows my message, but it shows the message from jBoss/Seam too ('please login first'). So I'm getting two error-messages on my `home.xhtml` page.

How can I prevent the error-message from Seam and only get my message?

Answer (score 1):

Override in your messages_en.properties the key:

```
org.jboss.seam.NotLoggedIn=your not logged in message
```

And remove your message key from pages.xml:

```
<exception class="org.jboss.seam.security.NotLoggedInException">
    <redirect view-id="/home.xhtml"/>
</exception>
```